# RPM fails to follow dependency order on install

Tags: linux, rpm, opensuse, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to force `rpm` to follow a given install order and it is not working as expected.  The `Requires` clause I added is not being respected.

I am doing a bare-metal Linux installer (openSUSE 42.2-based).  A whole system -- hundreds of packages -- are installed with one RPM command (using `--root`). I am having problems with three packages -- pam-config, pam-script, and openssh.  The pam-config `%post` scriptlet tries to modify files contained in pam-script and openssh but is installed, by default, before them.  It does not have dependencies by default, so, having the source, I rectified that by adding:

```
Requires: pam-script
Requires: openssh
```

to `pam-config.spec`.  (I also tried `Prereq:` with same results.)  As expected, with this change, it switches the ordering for pam-script and that error goes away.  But it steadfastly refuses to change the order of installation for openssh, which is installed two packages after pam-config.  [Openssh is dependent on coreutils and shadow (pwdutil), both of which are already installed at this point.  It's also dependent (`PreReq`) on a mysterious macro, `%{fillup_prereq}`.]

Everything else installs (and runs) just fine, but I would like to understand better how `rpm` works. I thought if I used `Required:` to specify openssh in pam-config, that openssh would invariably be installed before pam-config. It worked for pam-script.

`rpm -qp --requires` on the `.rpm` file shows openssh.  I repeated the install with the `-vv` option instead of `-v`. I can see the `Requires:` for openssh listed just the same as pam-script (`YES (added provide)`).  I see a `pam-config-0.91xxx -> openssh-7.2p2xxx` listed under `SCC #8: 11 members (100 external dependencies)`.  I see the install of pam-config, which has no dependency information and nothing remarkable except for the `%post` scriptlet command that generates the error (`pam-config --service sshd --delete --listfile`).  What other kind of things should I be looking at to debug this? What are these SCCs? Am I missing something about `Requires`? Or is there something obscure I may have overlooked, like circular, indirect, or hidden dependencies (I've checked for that, but ruled it out)? I've looked at several RPM tutorials and done a number of web searches and come up empty.

**UPDATE**:  It appears that unlike pam-script, openssh is caught up in a mutual-dependency critical section.  Here is the order of the packages actually being installed:

```
ruby2.1-rubygem-ruby-dbus-0.9.3-4.3.x86_64.rpm
pam-script-1.1.6-1.os42.gb01.x86_64.rpm
suse-module-tools-12.4-3.2.x86_64.rpm
kmod-17-6.2.x86_64.rpm
kmod-compat-17-6.2.x86_64.rpm
libcurl4-7.37.0-15.1.x86_64.rpm
pam-config-0.91-1.2.os42.gb01.x86_64.rpm
systemd-sysvinit-228-15.1.x86_64.rpm
krb5-1.12.5-5.13.x86_64.rpm
openssh-7.2p2-6.1.SBC.os42.gb01.x86_64.rpm
dracut-044-12.1.x86_64.rpm
systemd-228-15.1.x86_64.rpm
```

If I stage an installation on a production system and stop just before pam-config, it complains about being dependent on krb5, which is in the future!  If I stop at ruby, it works.  If I stop at pam-script, it works.  If I stop at suse-module-tools, it complains about dependencies on dracut. So I'm wondering if RPM abandons its ordering principle within a mutual-dependency critical section, or if there is a dependency I haven't uncovered yet.   I am using `rpm -q --requires` and `rpm -q --provides` to work this out.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Are you sure that `pam-config` is modifying a file owned by `openssh` and not by `openssh-server` nor `openssh-clients`?

Comment: Additional note. `sshd` is provided by `openssh-server`, not provided by `openssh`.

Comment: @alvits, in this distribution, openssh and openssh-server are folded together into one package.  I've confirmed the file I need, `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, is in package openssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more explicit sub-fields to the `Requires` tag, e.g. `Requires(post): openssh-server` or `Requires(pre,post): openssh-server`.

A single RPM transaction isn't *really* atomic, but is treated that way. Without this additional information, it just ensures that the packages are installed *by the end of this transaction*, which is "good enough" most of the time.

Another option is to put the required configuration into a `%triggerin` stanza, which I *believe* only executes once both packages are installed.

Comment: Great ideas!  `Requires(post)` does not work for me though.  `%triggerin` sounds very promising, but given the increasing complexity/risk I took a step back and determined it so happens I can delete the troublesome lines for other reasons, thus avoiding the problem. But I learned from your answer so I'm marking it as the chosen one.

Comment: Requires(post) is unlikely to solve an ordering problem that involves dependency loops without some study. If two packages require each other (i.e. a loop), then the order will usually default to de facto (i.e. first encountered, then the other). The best fix is to change the packaging to avoid dependency loops, often by adding another sub package.

Comment: An SCC is a strongly connected component in (Tarjan's) topological sort. RPM does a topological sort on dependencies to determine order. The existence of a SCC indicates a loop. The (usual) issue that needs solving is when a library script runs an executable that needs the library that is being installed (or similar). Again, changing the packaging to avoid the dependency loop is the best solution.

Comment: %triggerin doesn't guarantee "execution after both packages are installed" but is one approach. OTOH, triggers are quite sensitive to install ordering and so static dependency assertions used for ordering cannot be expressed generally. Trigger dependencies vs ordering gave their own chicken <-> egg snarliness.